# Comunication through Adapter to notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I implemented the situation described in the image below:

[image]

**The question is:**

I have to update the *gridView 2* when I update the *GridView 1*, how's the best way to do this? I could update the *GridView 2* only in its *Adapter* by do a new Volley Request, maybe I could do this by re-set the adapter in the *Fragment 2*, Could I use a reference to the *Fragment 2* in the *Adapter GridView 1* ?

**Details:**
The *GridView 1* is updated by a *notifyDataSetChanged()* on the *Adapter* performed after a Volley request by the *Adapter* itself. I can't use the *onResume()* method of *Fragment 2* because it's not called due to this fragment it's showed at the same time of the *Fragment 1*.

**Any Idea?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A listener is just an interface in JAVA. So you can not create an object of an interface ("new" operator)

1) Create an interface

```
public Interface OnUpdateGridView2Listener{
      public void onUpdate() //Add the kind of data you want in the parameters
}
```

2) Create a member of the interface in the adapter of gridView1 and call its method

```
public GidViewAdapter1 extends Adapter{
     private OnUpdateGridView2Listener myListener;

     //Your code

     @Override
     public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
           //Your code
           myListener.onUpdate();
     }

     public void setOnUpdateGridView2Listener(OnUpdateGridView2Listener list){  
           this.myListener = list;     
     }
}
```

3) Implement the interface in your fragment and notify the adapter

```
public FragmentGridView2 extends Fragment implements OnUpdateGridView2Listener{

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(){
            //Your code
            gridView2Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
}
```

4) In your activity, set the listener when you create your fragmentGridView1

```
public YourActivity{

      //Your code

      FragmentGridView1 fragment = new FragmentGridView1();
      fragment.setOnUpdateGridView2Listener(getApplication());
}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use EventBus or Otto library.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to implement a Listener pattern like this:

```
FragmentTab2 {

    private interface DataListener {
        public Data getData();
    }

    private DataListener dataListener = new DataListener();

    Data = dataListener.getData();

}


FragmentTab1 implements DataListener {

    @Override
    public Data getData() {
        return Data;
    }

}
```

Or a bit more involved should you need to notify, register, and unregister listeners try this here: [Observer Design Pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)